# Joomla 3.x category blog override, is it possible to have more than one?

Tags: joomla

I am working with Joomla! 3.2 with a custom template.

Now I have already overriden the blog.php file from the folder `components/com_content/views/category/tmpl` into `mytemplate/html/com_content/category` where I have now my sweet and very useful blog.php file with my custom HTML mark up.

Now my question is...
Is it possible to have more than one file blog.php-like? For instance blog.php, news.php, products.php in order to have more custom overrides in the same template?

Comment: Have a look at this question on the Joomla SE: [Creating multiple layout overrides for category blog layout](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8971/creating-multiple-layout-overrides-for-category-blog-layout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as above and whatever Elin said plus you might have to copy blog_item.php to your template_name\html\com_content\category as well and rename it eg. my-blog.php, my-blog.xml, my-blog_item.php, etc.

Comment: When you say "same as above", what are you referring to? What did Elin say?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "Yes!" There is one caveat though. When you copied the blog.php over to your template, there should have also been a blog.xml file in the template as well. You will want to copy that file over and name it the same as your new php files (news.xml, products.xml, etc).

Then open this xml file and change the third line that reads something like this:

```
<layout title="COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_VIEW_BLOG_TITLE" option="COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_VIEW_BLOG_OPTION">
```

to a different title:

```
<layout title="News Layout" option="COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_VIEW_BLOG_OPTION">
```

I wouldn't worry about setting up a translated string like what was there unless you are planning to release this template or have multiple languages on the back end.

With that change, look for your new layout when adding a menu item. When adding a menu item, select the menu item type, open up the articles section, and you should see the title that you set now in the list, and it will link to the new layout php file that you created!

Comment: You don't actually need to do that if you don't need the menu link. All you need to do is call the layouts with different names and they will show up in the alternate layout drop down list.

Comment: @Elin Is that true for component layouts too? I thought that was only for module layouts.

Comment: Frisch, Yes it's true for components also; the choices for components are limited to the layouts without a corresponding xml. So .. with xml you can only use when creating a menu item, without xml you can only use when editing/creating an item itself.

Comment: Hi Fritsch, that was exactly what I was looking for! (Sorry! I still don't have enough reputation to arrow it up) Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: @ A. D'Alfonso You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the question though! Then everyone knows that you are good.